# Delphi XE8 iOS Application not running on iPhone 6 but works on other models

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, delphi-xe8

My application developed on Delphi Firemonkey XE8 (Update 1) failes to run on iPhone 6 but works on IPhone 4 and IPad4 (All iOS 8.4).

XCode 6.4 and iOS 6.4 SDK's imported.

Any help to on how to figure out why it will on one device and not the other given the iOS versions are the same?

Strangely enough, this specific project does not want to run on iOS simulator. When running with the Delphi debugger I hangs in the Begin with Process dlym_sim. Running the app stand alone from iOS Simulator I get a crash report:

[Crash Report loaded here](https://www.formidablesolutions.com/MobileSync_2015-07-14-153433_Dev-Mac.crash.txt)

Comment: Using the instruments Application in Xcode. recording the app in Simulator gives the following reason for the crash on startup:
dyld: Symbol not found: _pthread_self
  Referenced from: /Users/willemvanzyl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3A007E6-CB1B-418B-8758-FA43A244ADB4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/802CED40-284E-40AE-BAE6-19E1EE330231/MobileSync.app/MobileSync
  Expected in: /Users/willemvanzyl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3A007E6-CB1B-418B-8758-FA43A244ADB4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/802CED40-284E-40AE-BAE6-19E1EE330231/MobileSync.app/MobileSync
End of Run